Competition vs Group interest question based on Andy Grove's book named High Output Management
In High Output Management Andy talks about self insert and group interest and encourages the later especially in high CUA (complexity, uncertainty, ambiguity) environment. But later he talks about a manager being like a sports coach by nurturing competition in his group to reach the highest performance hopefully appealing to self-actualization motivation. How competition and the group interest go together?
